# Reset Button in Filter Popup

Tags: buttons, filter, dropdown, dialog

How should the Reset button on popup work? Should the window be closed?

1. You need to close the window. The filter is reset, the table is updated
2. The window does not close, all items in the list are unselected, the table is not updated
3. Other

**Common Behavior**

Change of popup list item state doesn't update the table.

Save: apply filter, close the popup, update table.

Cancel: close popup, changes of list options are ignored, table is not updated.

Filter button states are presented in the right pane.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`[Reset]         [Filter]  [Cancel]`

**Reset**: restore last saved filter to the list, don't change table, don't close popup.

**Filter**: apply to table and save changes, close popup.

**Cancel**: don't apply to table, don't save changes, close popup.

Resetting the filter doesn't imply closing the popup. Cancelling implies both resetting and closing.

Also, Saving doesn't imply applying nor closing. Filtering does.